# How do I add proxy support into my python script? (reddit api wrapper python)

Tags: python, reddit

Here is some code:

```
import reddit
usernames = ['username', 'username1', 'username2'] proxy_list = ['ip', 'ip2', 'ip3'] 
cycle = 0
accounts = 3 print "enter url" item = raw_input() 
r = reddit.Reddit(user_agent='my_cool_application')
while cycle < accounts:
#code to connect to a proxy

    r.login(usernames[cycle], "password")
    print "%r logged in" %usernames[cycle]
    submission = r.get_submission(item)

    submission.upvote()
    print "%r voted" %usernames[cycle]
    cycle = cycle + 1 
print "Upvoted %r times" %cycle
```

This uses the reddit mellort api. The accounts are not real. The ips are not real duh. This script is supposed to upvote a post multiple times. The code is pretty self explanatory. THis code works but only upvotes the post once because of ip. I just need the code, as marked above, that will connect to a proxy before logging in and upvoting so that each upvote comes from a different ip. Please help me out I am getting very frustrated. Please just give provide some code to replace "#code to connect to a proxy". I know a lot of people are looking for a solution to this problem out. Help the Python brethren out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What system are you using? If linux, it's pretty easy.(Since twitter is blocked here, so, only with proxy can I access it)

```
import urllib2
import os

os.environ['http_proxy'] = "http://10.8.0.1:8118/"
print urllib2.urlopen("http://twitter.com").read()
```